# Localization issue during indexing double fields in Sitecore

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I have issue with Sitecore 7.5 and Lucene indexing. I have items with the "latitude" Single-Line Text field. This field stores double numbers with point (not comma). 
I set culture on my computer as en-US so it should work with such numbers. Also I set IIS culture the same. But when I rebuild index I get the following error:

```
17840 01:46:43 FATAL Could not add field {25D5A28F-F502-42CE-8FDD-C6432E64AE67} : latitude for indexable sitecore://web/{94D5DBF1-FEB9-464B-B887-A99181B58268}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.FormatException
Message: Input string was not in a correct format.
Source: mscorlib

   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)

   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)

   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)

   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneFieldBuilder.CreateField(String name, Object value, LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration fieldConfiguration, IIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter indexFieldStorageValueFormatter)

   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddField(String name, Object value, LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration fieldSettings, Single boost)

   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddField(IIndexableDataField field)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.CheckAndAddField(IIndexable indexable, IIndexableDataField field)
```

I tried to debug these methods and found out that System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is "ru-RU" inside the Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneFieldBuilder.CreateField() method.
But in my c# code I have System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture set as "en-US". I checked this in debug mode.
So how can it be possible that CurrentCulture is changed during the indexing process? I don't have "ru-RU" setting either in Windows or IIS culture settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrei I'd the same issue (working with a stored procedures in MS SQL) a few months ago.

I've changed default culture to "en-US" on both my local machine (Windows 10) and IIS. Unfortunately, it hasn't helped me. In my case, I rewrote my stored procedure where I replaced delimiters in double numbers.

So, it's really complicated issue. I think you should reinstall the OS in your local machine using installer with ENG version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code from command line:

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:globalization /culture:en-us
```

It [will set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836(v=ws.10).aspx) your culture to "en-us".

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I ran this command and it set IIS culture to "en-us". Then I restarted IIS and rebuilt index. The same error appeared in logs.